# What is this strange character and how can I get rid of It?

Tags: .net, string, vba, powerpoint

This shows up in both .NET and in VBA. The male sign:

```
♂
```

[image: mo fo]

You'll notice on lines 4, 5, 6, 8, 10 and 12 there is an extra character there. This is from a paragraph mark. On line 3 is a tab character, but that just shows up as spaces.

This happens when I try to grab the text of a `.TextRange.Text` in PowerPoint. Above is the Immediate Window in the VBE, but it also shows up .NET controls when I try to put the text in a control, such as a ListView.

It can be replicated by opening a new PowerPoint presentation and then in the VBE running:

```
Sub Replicate()
    Dim ap As Presentation: Set ap = ActivePresentation
    Dim sl As Slide: Set sl = ap.Slides(1)
    sl.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "One bad" & vbCrLf & "MOFO"
    Debug.Print s.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
End Sub
```

How can I get rid of this (i.e. just show nothing in place of the male sign)? Is this some kind of Unicode setting for my controls or RegEx on the string or...?

Comment: Wouldn't a better title use "manly awesomeness" instead of "mofo"? :P

Comment: @GWW: yeah, maybe. I've just so pissed off this morning at this male sign thing. My anger reflected in the title.

Comment: Oh, I completely understand that.

Comment: normally i would just edit the expletive out of the title, but out of respect i'll leave it up to you. Surely the anger has subsided by now?

Comment: Looks like someone else edited it out, which is fine, I couldn't bring myself to do it. I'm still angry. It will always be a mofo to me. :(

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Powerpoint is not using the same carriage-return line-feed convention that VB is using.  You might have to replace the vbCrLf with a different newline convention (make your own byte array pair to insert).

Answer (score 0):

instead of `vbCrLf`  Use this `vbLf & vbCr`

```
Sub Replicate()
    Dim ap As Presentation: Set ap = ActivePresentation
    Dim sl As Slide: Set sl = ap.Slides(1)
    sl.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "One bad" & vbLf & vbCr & "Line Feed above me"
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: That still produces the male sign in output. But the idea is to handle the output or the control that hosts the output. An end-user isn't going to use VBA to insert a paragraph mark - the code is there just to show how it can be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

This article will help [Exploring the PowerPoint TextRange Object](http://www.clear-lines.com/blog/post/Exploring-the-PowerPoint-TextRange-object.aspx), but note that when it's from a title placeholder it is Chr(11) instead of Chr(13). You can use a `TextRange.Replace(ChrW(11), " ")` on it to clean it up.